# Role creation issue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I login to my snowflake trial account and changed role to accountadmin. Created new user and role. assigned COMPUTE_WH to new user.

I login to snowflake with new userid but unable to select warehouse or any action. Could you please let me know what is missing.

Thanks,
Yash

Answer (score 2):

Good chance that you granted a role to the user and granted the warehouse to the role.  However, a new user's default role will be PUBLIC, so when you log into Snowflake using the new user, you need to change their role to the new role that you created.  Then, you'll see the warehouse.

You can also go back in as accountadmin and change the default role for the new user to the new role you created.

Comment: Thanks Mike for reply. I executed below command and after that i am able to select warehouse with new user login but getting below error.     grant operate on warehouse compute_wh to role myrole;   error getting SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on warehouse 'COMPUTE_WH'

Comment: You can't grant yourself access to a warehouse.  You need to use your accountadmin role to grant operate privs to your new role.